# Prove that a polynomial has degree two

Tags: polynomials

Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial that satisfies $x*f(x-2)=(x-4)*f(x)$. Proof that $f(x)$ has a degree of 2.

What I've tried was substituting $f(x)$ with $ax^2+bx+c$ and ended up with $4ax+2bx+4c=0$, which didn't help much.

Comment: Maybe try and substitute $x=0$?

Comment: That is a strange way to start. Basically you seem to assume that $\deg f(x)=2$, so anything you can get from there feels like circular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute $x=0$, then $x=4$ to get that $f(0) = f(2) = 0$. Hence $f(x) = x(x-2)h(x)$. Use that to get that $h$ is a periodic polynomial, hence a constant.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x)=f(2x)$, so that $xg(x-1)=(x-2)g(x)$. We can assume $g$ is monic.

So $x(g(x)-g(x-1))=2g(x)$. With binomial formulas, you can check that the leading coefficient of the LHS is the degree of $g$, thus the degree of $f$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm a 7th grader and I don't really understand :)

Comment: I do not think you can assume $g$ monic.

Comment: @JCAA: I can, because multiplying $g$ by a constant doesn't change the hypothesis nor the conclusion. But anyway, if $g$ has leading coefficient $\alpha$, then the leading coefficient of the LHS is $\alpha\deg{g}$ while the leading coefficient of the RHS is $2\alpha$.

Comment: @lolman981234: Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Mindlack: The leading coefficients of $xg(x-1)$ and $(x-2)g(x)$ are equal to the leading coefficient of $g$. The first statement in your last comment is also wrong: $2/\alpha\ne 2$.

Comment: @JCAA: No, I am speaking of the LHS and RHS of my modified equation: $x(g(x)-g(x-1))=2g(x)$.

Comment: @Mindlack: The leading coefficient of $x(g(x)-g(x-1))$ depends on the non-leading coefficient of $g$. If you do not think so, provide a proof of your statement. The phase "it follows from binomial formula" is not enough.

Comment: @JCAA: Write $g(x)=\alpha x^n+ux^{n-1}+O(x^{n-2})$, then $g(x)-g(x-1)=\alpha(x^n-(x-1)^n)+u(x^{n-1}-(x-1)^{n-1})+O(x^{n-2}) = n\alpha x^{n-1} + O(x^{n-2})$ by the binomial formula.

Comment: @Mindlack: This is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots$, then$$xf(x-2)=a_nx^{n+1}+(a_n-2na_{n-1})x^n+\cdots\tag1$$and$$(x-4)f(x)=a_{n-1}x^{n+1}+(a_n-4a_{n-1})x^++\cdots\tag2$$So, in order to have $(1)=(2)$, and since $a_n\ne0$, you must have $4=2n$, which means that $n=2$.